# Why can't read the data submitted along with the files?

Tags: multer, ng-file-upload

The first thing I do is send the ID of the folder with ng-file-upload module.

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: '/api/files/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        file: file,
        folderId: currentFolder // This is the information I want to receive
    }
})...;
```

I receive the information on the following route:

```
router.route('/api/files/upload').post(files.uploadFiles);
```

Then when I try to check the information, the ID doesn't exist!

But the strangest thing is that in other parts of the code I can get the ID, is very confusing. You can look at the pictures to understand me better.

Here's the code to upload a file:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('lodash');
var async = require('async');
var multer = require('multer');
var errorHandler = require('./errorhandler.server.controller.js');

var Files = mongoose.model('Files');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        //
        // req.body.folderId EXISTS !!!
        // but I don't understand why don't exist in the other places
        // you can see the picture 2
        //
        cb(null, path.resolve(req.ubicacion));
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        //
        // req.body.folderId doesn't exist
        //
        fs.exists(req.ubicacion + file.originalname, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                return cb(new Error('Ya existe ' + file.originalname));
            }
            cb(null, true);
        });
    }
}).any();

/**
 *
 */
exports.uploadFiles = function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(cb) {
            //
            // req.body.folderId doesn't exist
            // you can see the picture 1
            //
            var id = req.body.folderId;

            Files.findById(id, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                req.ubicacion = result.ubicacion;
                cb(null);
            });
        },
        function(cb) {
            upload(req, res, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                cb(null);
            });
        },
        function(cb) {
            var file = new Files({});

            file.save(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return cb(err);
                }
                cb(null, result);
            });
        }
    ], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                err: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json(result);
    });
};
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui5O6.jpg) and [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1voF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When a HTTP request is made with content, the `req.body` is not populated with the content magically, it needs to be done manually, or use a middleware to do it in our place.

For form without file, `body-parser` is one of the most used middleware, but it does not handle multipart form.

The middleware `multer` does this work when, in your code, the function named `upload` is called.

This explains why at the start of `uploadFile`, `folderId` is not accessible, because `upload` is only called after, in this part of code :

```
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err);
    }
    cb(null);
});
```